# Get the width of custom element created using <polymer-element> in dart?

Tags: dart, dart-polymer, dart-html

How do I get the width of a custom element from the element's script?

```dart
<polymer-element name="his-elem">
  <div>
    blah
  </div>
</polymer-element>

@CustomTag('his-elem')
class blah extends PolymerElement {

  @override
  void attached() {
    // how do I get the <his-elem>'s width (just width, no padding border stuff) here?
    // document.querySelector('his-elem').getComputedStyle().width gives me "auto"...
  }

}
```

**Update**

Add `:host {display: block;}` to his-element, then you can get the actual width via `<his-elem>.clientWidth`.

Answer (score 2):

I use this when the other methods don't work:

```dart
this.getBoundingClientRect().width
```

See also https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.getBoundingClientRect

**In Polymer <= 0.16

you need to call `super.attached()` previously

```dart
  @override
  void attached() {
    super.attached();
    print(this.getBoundingClientRect().width);
    // or 
    print(this.getComputedStyle().width);
  }
```

before the call to `super.attached()` the element isn't yet attached to the DOM and won't return a proper width. Actually with overriding `attached` and not calling `super.attached()` within the method you prevent attaching.

Comment: Could you add a little mortar to this brick-only answer?

Answer (score 1):

*this* represents the html element itself. So it should be *this.style.width*.

Comment: It's empty, and `this.clientWidth` gives 0.

Comment: what returns this.getComputedStyle().width

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer It's also "auto".

Comment: @NotanID you have to call this method inside `domReady` callback.